# Android how to display two ListViews in one AlertDialog one after the other

Tags: android, listview, row, android-linearlayout, android-alertdialog

I have two list. One list show all available items (lv_available_items) and second only selected items (lv_selected_items) from available list. I want also that selected list takes maximum 50% of display, for this I use attribute “layout_weight”. But if it’s only one item from available list selected, this is not fully displayed in selected list. Why?

View for AlertDialog:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_selected_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_available_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Row for this two list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right|center_vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/cb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onClickRow"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshots:

http://windows.valloc.de/msl1.png

http://windows.valloc.de/msl2.png

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `height` to `0dp` in your `ListView`s

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_selected_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">
    </ListView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_available_items"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Manage the height of listview like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/lv1"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
 <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/lv1"
    android:scrollingCache="false"/>
```

Comment: Yes i can do this, but i don't want a fixed size, for different devices.

Comment: Try these methods one is set height wrap_content and another one is              design  customize listview.

Answer (score -1):

you will design xml according to your different emulators.Like for hdpi phone resolution    design .xml file according to his view you can select hpdi emulator from graphical view in .xml file and then design different .xml for ldpi,xhdpi,etc.It is little bit time consuming but effective one

Then used Display metric class in .java file

```
  DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    screenWidthPX = metrics.widthPixels;
    screenHeightPX = metrics.heightPixels;
    densityDpi = metrics.densityDpi;
    switch(metrics.denistyDpi)
    {
        case DisplayMetrics.Denisty_High:
        R.id.high.xml;   //pass xml id of high denisty 
    }
```

//Similarly another case pass Denisty_low and so on;

Comment: This answer is _completely_ unrelevant to the question.